# Render user entered data in rescue block if update fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rest-client

I have rails  5.0.1 app (App 1) working which uses another Rails API for database operations.
App 1 is not using active record but using flexirest for Api calls.

When create or update method is called, all the data is sent to rails api in json format.
i want when api throws any error, it should be catch in rescue block and also the data which user entered before submit click should be render after rescue using render :edit (for update) or render :new (for create)

here is my code

```
    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        begin
          if @booking.update({id: @booking.booking.id, booking: booking_params})  
            format.html { redirect_to excel_front_innstats_path, notice: display_notice(t("label.detailed_reservation.reservation")) }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
          end
        rescue => e
          #here assign the booking object with user entered data, 
          #so that the form will not loose the data
          #if exception occurs

          flash_error_message(:error, e.result)
          format.html { render :edit }
        end  
      end
    end
```

Comment: Add the result of your code, difference between what you think and the result

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @artgb now edit renders the view with data which is in database, i want the data from the form which user has submitted.

Comment: You have to change view to use booking params

Comment: In my edit view, i am using this <%= form_for (@booking.booking), url: excel_front_detailed_reservation_path(@booking.booking[:id]), method: :put, do |f| %>

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented easily, you need to make some changes in **edit.html.erb** form of **@booking**.

When rendering **edit.html.erb** make sure to check respective input field values exists in **params hash or not**. If values exists assign field value from params else assign field value from @booking.

**For example Edit(Update):**

```
<input type='text' name='booking_name' value="<%= params[:booking_name] ? params[:booking_name] : @booking.booking_name%>"/>
```

**For example New(Ureate):**

```
<input type='text' name='booking_name' value="<%= params[:booking_name]%>"/>
```

I hope you got the approach.

Comment: It's not smart way I think